# How t o enter properly instructions to widen margins a page for RMarkdown pdf.doc

Tags: r, r-markdown, chunks, margins

Since I'm facing with an incorrected reporting into pages in RMarkdown, as you could see here:

[image]

I was suggested to enter these commands around the line that is supposed to print the table.

````
<span style='font-size: 0.8em'>
```{r model, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
iwalk(tables_models, ~ cat(knitr::knit_print(.x)))
```
</span>
````

Since I've tried to reproce that into my doc as follows

[image]

Producing red marks and the only way I found to make them set correctly is this:

[image]

that does not make the problem fixed, I would like to ask help to set these instructions properly. Thanks

Comment: You want to make a special margin only for one page?

Comment: No actually it's for several pages (those obe that are just included in that code), because some beforehand and afterwards are ok

Comment: In a word, not for the all document. Yes? Knitting to pdf? or both to word and pdf?

Comment: Just to pdf. Awyway, right, not for everything.

Comment: Then, i know an answer. Moment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a special margin in your file (**knitting to pdf**), then try this LaTeX-solution:

Add this package to the header:

```
header-includes: 
 \usepackage{geometry}
```

Make a special margin for some pages (you also can use mm, cm):

```
\newgeometry{top=1in,left=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in}
```

And after return to your previous style:

```
\restoregeometry
```

**An example to you:**

````
---
title: "R"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{geometry}
output:
  pdf_document: default
---  

\newgeometry{top=1in,left=5in,bottom=1in,right=1in}

```{r}
options(width = 100)
matrix(runif(100), ncol = 20)
```
\restoregeometry      

\newpage
\newgeometry{top=1in,left=0in,bottom=1in,right=1in}

```{r}
options(width = 100)
matrix(runif(100), ncol = 20)
```
\restoregeometry  

\newpage
\newgeometry{top=5in,left=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in}

```{r}
options(width = 100)
matrix(runif(100), ncol = 20)
```
\restoregeometry
````

Comment: Ok, does this solution recognize automatically the pages that needs to be wider?

Comment: no, you should add by yourself

Comment: The problem is that if I do not where that pages appear, I cannot set this parametres and actually I cannot get evn how to set them.

Comment: Then maybe will be better to pick up a more suitable margin for all document...? Are these your theses?

Comment: No axmctually, it is just a report for showing research results. By the way if I need just to set better the code that has been provided into my post, I will need just to figure out how to locate them.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ok, but actually I didn't get hoow to locate those istructions

Comment: I added an example, try to knit

Comment: You are very kind. But I am still in trouble

Comment: Write, i try to help, if i could

Comment: If I need to fit your solution to my case, where exactly I should enter the commands and which is the order? If you can, just try explaing like you should have in front the chunk I've post.

Comment: I don't want peculiar, maybe I'm quite off for today. Sorry

Comment: If i were on your place, i' ll made a test document with 3 - 5 pages with your tables, to discover a pattern.  By eye is hard to say.

Comment: May I ask you whether we can text each other on a private chat as suggested.I do not if you have any, but I do know how to creaue it. At least I can share pics there. Do you agree? For tomorrow